# How in app to GET some specific data from JSON-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Please help me to get only what i want from server. I don't understand how this do.
SERVER side:

```
{ 
'data': [ 
{ 'count': 'test', 
'title': 'test', 
'size': 2, 'id': 1 
}, 
{ 'count': 'test', 
'title': 'test', 
'size': 2, 'id': 2 
}, 
{ 'count': 'test', 
'title': 'test', 
'size': 2, 
'id': 3 
}
```

And my actions from APP side:

```
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(res => { 
this.setState({ data: res}, () => {console.log('data: ', res)})})

data: Array [
Object { 
{ 
'count': 'test',
'title': 'test',
'size': 2,
'id': 1 
}, 
{
'count': 'test',
'title': 'test',
'size': 2,
'id': 2
},
{
'count': 'test',
'title': 'test',
'size': 2,
'id': 3
}
}
]
```

But, i want to GET only 'count' and 'title'.

Comment: Is server code in your control or it is a third party API?

Comment: The server should return accordingly.Or you have to create new array from response.

Comment: @bennygenel Thank you for your support!

Comment: @M14 And thank you for your support too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get only 'count' and 'title'.

Then use `map` method and *destructing*. The *map()* method creates a new array with the results of calling a *provided* function on every element in the calling **array**.

```js
let data = [ { 'count': 'test', 'title': 'test', 'size': 2, 'id': 1 }, { 'count': 'test', 'title': 'test', 'size': 2, 'id': 2 }, { 'count': 'test', 'title': 'test', 'size': 2, 'id': 3 } ]

console.log(data.map(({count, title}) => ({count, title})));
```

Comment: Thank you very match for your help. This is what I need.